# vertically centering certain text

Tags: css

Hi I have an image right here

[image: http://puu.sh/eeOTZ/1e14f8b0ce.png]

and the text is pushed on the top?

Is there a property that will make it in the center?

**Here is the CSS I have tried.**

```
 text-align: center;
 margin: center;
```

Comment: Please add the HTML & CSS you used to create the content in the image.

Comment: Redraw your image to center the text. :) Seriously, though, you'll need to provide your markup as well as the minimum CSS necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You need `line-height` for this. I have added your own image for reference too:

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 10pt;}
.tabs, .tabs li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; display: block;}
.tabs li {display: inline-block; background-color: #ccc; line-height: 50px; padding: 0 10px; border-top: 2px solid #999;}

.theImg {background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/rld5h.png") center center no-repeat; line-height: 45px; width: 122px; text-align: center; margin: 20px; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<!-- Using your code! -->

<div class="theImg">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image in a div with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <img src="" alt="img" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use display tables like this: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/34/

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="text">This is my text</div>
</div>

.outside {
    display: table;
    background-color:lightgray;
    height:200px;
}

.text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the `line-height` to the height of your element:

```css
.tab {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rld5h.png);
  width: 122px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tab">Text</div>
```

(I reused your image in the example, hence two times the text.)